# Не одна (,) так другая.

Tags: фразеология, пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую в устойчивом выражении "не одна(,) так другая"?
Изменится ли ситуация, если добавить глагол:
"Не одна(,) так другая.", "Не одна(,) так другая взбрыкнет."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

От глагола ничего не зависит, а запятую можно поставить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!